# How can I add a mouseover effect to a span?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to do something, like when you Mouseover on text inside a span, the background changes.
My code:

```
<script>
    function unhighlight(x) {
        x.style.backgroundColor="transparent"
    }

    function highlight(x) {
        x.style.backgroundColor="red"
    }
</script>


<span onmouseover="highlight(this)" onmouseout="unhighlight(this)">
    <h2>What's New</h2>
</span>
```

The reason I don't apply it to the h2 is a little complicated. Don't need to explain. Help?

Comment: Since no one has mentioned yet, I'd add that `<h2>` is **NOT** a valid content for `<span>` element. In fact the permitted content of `<span>` is *[phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content)*. Therefore you'd better use `<div>` element rather than `<span>`, probably.

Comment: If you want to highlight the text itself rather than the whole space, you should wrap the content of `<h2>` by an inline container line `<span>` element. Then apply the background color on `h2 > span:hover` - **[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/j8ncbnLt/1/)**.

Answer (score 7):

Your javacript is fine.

> The span element is the inline level generic container. It also helps
>   to inform the structure of document, but it is used to group or wrap
>   other inline elements and/or text, rather than block level elements.

So `h2` is not valid child for `span`:

[html standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#phrasing-content-2)

```js
function unhighlight(x) {
  x.style.backgroundColor = "transparent"
}

function highlight(x) {
  x.style.backgroundColor = "red"
}
```

```css
span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<span onmouseover="highlight(this);" onmouseout="unhighlight(this)"><h2>What's New</h2></span>
```

I suggest for containers to use block elements like `div`. And also i suggest to use css for this:

```css
div:hover {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h2>What's New</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: It is not related to `width`, nor `height` the `block` display type did the trick here. The point is that `<span>` is an inline wrapper and the markup is totally invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Just set CSS to `<span>`

```
display: block;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your span element to an inline block for this to work :

```
span {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

But note that you can achieve the same effect with CSS only :

```
span {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: transparent;
}
span:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need javascript to do it, just with **HTML** and **CSS** **:**

```css
    #myText {
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: transparent;
    }
    #myText:hover {
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
<span id="myText"><h2>What's New</h2></span>
```